# Why is my image not transparent and how can I make it so?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I am adding a couple images to my site and some of them are transparent but others aren't being transparent even though they are supposed to be. I've set the background to be transparent on my images so I'm not sure why it's not working here. The fourth block is the one where I'm having a problem and the image is not being transparent.

[image]

[image]

**css**

```
.stat-numbers img{
    background:transparent;
    width:100%;
    filter: grayscale(1) brightness(200) contrast(0) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(55deg) saturate(20);
}
```

**html**

```
                    <div class="row stat-numbers">
                            <div class="col-4 transparent"></div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <img src="gun.png" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <img src= "crosshair.png" class="sm-image img-responsive">
                                </div>
                                <div class="points">18</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1 transparent">

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <img src="helmet2.png" class=" helmet-icon img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <img src="energy.png" style="background:transparent;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="points">18</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <div class="icon">R</div>
                                <div class="points">18</div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-2 transparent"></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Are they all .pngs with transparent background? If the images are not transparent in png format themselves, I don't think there is a way in CSS to make them transparent.

Comment: @DavidLiang I'm saving all of them as png when I save the photo, but I'm not sure all of them are png's originally

Comment: You could try and use something like https://remove.bg or a different service which removes the background for you.

Comment: Just double check them with a photo editor.

Comment: @Ezrab_ Ah ok, will try that

Comment: @Ezrab_ Thanks that worked lol